# How to increase COMMITTED_CPUS quota?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I tried to purchase additional committed use discount in GCP but I got this error.

> Quota 'COMMITTED_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 75.0 in region asia-southeast1.

Previously, I already purchase some CPU and memory successfully. I tried to search in Quota page but I can't find anything with `COMMITTED_CPUS` or `75` limits. Digging to commitments metric only purchase quota not cpu quota.

[image: Commitments Quota]

I also try this command but still can't find it.

> gcloud compute project-info describe --project "project_name"

I can't purchase it both in console and using this command.

> gcloud compute commitments create asia-southeast-1y-3 --plan 12-month --region asia-southeast1 --resources=MEMORY=106GB,VCPU=36

Comment: If you have a support contact, I would think Google should be glad to help you reserve more of their servers.  After all, it helps them make money.  Unfortunately, it is not a question stack overflow can answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've confront this issue before. I can provide you some SOP for solving this:

File a new case to increase your COMMITMENTS quota in the same region you’re seeing the problem in order to address the problem in an automated way. Each COMMITMENTS increase also increases COMMITTED_CPUS to the current quota of CPUS in the region.

**To be very specific, if you need an increase for COMMITTED_CPUS, the only way is to request an increase for COMMITMENTS.** To request quota for Commitments, follow these instructions:

- Go to the Quota Increase page in the Google Cloud Platform Console
- Expand the Quota type dropdown menu and select All quotas.
- Expand the Metric dropdown menu.
- Click on None to hide all quotas and then type Commitments in the search box to search for Commitments quota.
- Select Commitments from the list.
- Select the checkbox next to Commitments for the desired region and click the Edit Quotas button.
- If prompted, fill in your first and last name, and phone number. Click Next.
- Fill out the request form and click Next.
- Click Submit Request to submit your request.

Once your request is received, it takes about 2 business days. Hope this helps!

Comment: What does the quantity in the limit stand for ? The count of cpus or a $ amount or something else.  Commitments are for CPU and memory so $ seems to make more sense but?